Questions relating to the definition of the Frechet derivative
My knowledge in multivarible calculas or real analysis is very limited. Please excuse the possibly ill-posed question and the use of intuivive explanation. Thanks for your understanding.
As I understand, a function $f$: $\textbf{R}^{n}$ -> $\textbf{R}^{m}$ has a Frechet derivative (i.e. is differentiable) at a x $\in$ $\textbf{int dom} f$ if there exists a linear map $Df(x)$ from $\textbf{R}^{n}$ -> $\textbf{R}^{m}$ satisfying $$\lim_{z\in\textbf{dom}f, z\rightarrow x} \frac{||f(z)-f(x)-Df(x)(z-x)||}{||z-x||} =0$$
I get how this is a generalization of the "usual" derivative, I also intuitively get why this derivative should be the Jacobian of $f$ at $x$.
My question is this: why should there be a $||z-x||$ at the denominator?
Because according to my intuitive understanding, we want to find $Df(x)$ such that for any "small" $z-x\in \textbf{R}^{n}$ (i.e. $||z-x||$ is small), $f(x)+Df(x)(z-x)$ is "close" to $f(z)$, and they can be however close we want as long as z-x is small enough. Then this $||z-x||$, to me, not only seem redundent, but even wrong, since this may rule out a actually "valid" (according to my intuitive understanding) $Df(x)$ since $||f(z)-f(x)-Df(x)(z-x)||$ may in fact converges to $0$, but not "faster" than $||z-x||$.
My current guess is that this will never happen, but even so, why include $||z-x||$ then?

Just imagine it was a Taylor series in the numerator. You would need to zero out all the non-linear terms as $z$ tends to $x$.

Compare with one dimensional derivatives: $f’(a)$ is the limit as $x\to a$ of the quotient $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Or in other words, the quotient $\frac{|f(x)-f(a)-f’(a)(x-a)|}{|x-a|}$ vanishes as $x\to a$.

"$f(x)+Df(x)(z-x)$ is "close" to $f(z)$, and they can be however close we want as long as z-x is small enough", and "$||f(z)-f(x)-Df(x)(z-x)||$ may in fact converges to $0$, but not "faster" than $||z-x||$", are too weak. It is not what the definition intends to convey, because if so, $Df(x)$ could be replaced by any linear map $Df(x)+L$ (since $L(z-x)$ can be "however close we want" to $0$ "as long as z-x is small enough").

@AnneBauval Oh right, I didn't notice that.  Can you point me in the direction of showing that when $Df(x)$ is the jacobian of $f$ at $x$, then the limit is not indeterminate but does tend to 0 ? This is easy to show with one-dimensiomal derivative, since the absolute norm can be "factored out", but with higher dimension I am at a loss.

If possible, I would hope for an explanation without too much real analysis. Even a "intuitive but complete" one would do (I encounter this in the appendix of a book, so I just want to make myself believe it.)

Assume for instance that $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ satisfies $f(0,0)=0$ and for some linear map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R,(u,v)\mapsto au+bv$:
$$\lim_{(u,v)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(u,v)-(au+bv)}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}=0.$$
Then, you will easily derive that $Jf_{(0,0)}=(a\ b)$.
